# ubuntu : how to clear $SHELL history

Tags: shell, ubuntu

```
No command 'exprt' found, did you mean:
 Command 'expr' from package 'coreutils' (main)
exprt: command not found
```

i got this msg everytime i open the terminal. 'exprt' is my typo error during installation. I've tried

```
# history -c
# history -cw
```

but it still can't get rid of this problem, especially when

```
# exec $SHELL
```

it prompt the same error as well

any solution? I'm newbie to ubuntu...

Comment: If you get this error every time you _start_ a shell (terminal window), then it's not related to the history feature, but to one of your shell profiles - see @NicholasM's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could this just be a typo in one of your shell configuration files?

Try running the following to search your .profile, .bash_profile, .bashrc, and so on for the offending line:

```
grep 'exprt' ~/.*
```

If you find the typo, edit the line so that is says "export" instead of "exprt", if that is what it should be.